# Calculate "forward" percentage

Tags: percentages

Ok, now I just made that concept up and I will try to explain what I need in a second, note that it might have a different name but I cant seem to find what I need on the internet.

I am trying to set up some prices for a product. 
Here is what i have:

`Cost      Wholesale price         Retail Price
 $10            $15                     ?`

Now here is the problem, I want to set the retail price such as that when I do a 30% discount I get the wholesale price I have set up.

It seems pretty simple to do if I know the retail price and not the whole sale because I can use this formula: `tax = (price * percentage) / (1 + percentage)`.

With that formula I can calculate the wholesale price from my Retail price but I want to do it the other way around...

How can I (based on my wholesale price) calculate forward to get my retail price such as that i can do a 30% discount and get the wholesale price that i set up?

Comment: Discount is before or after tax?

Comment: we can forget about tax right now edit: the **tax formula** is something that can be useful to do some calculations but i dont care about tax at the moment

Comment: Uh okay... what do you think of my answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your whole sale price is 70% of the retail price.  You can just divide your wholesale price price by 7 and multiply it by 10.

Comment: yep i got the message saying that i can only do that once a minute (was on another thread a few mins ago) :)

Thanks for the help!